# Host Websites on Virtual IP VMs

Tags: virtual-machines, qemu, private-ip

I have Proxmox Virtulization server installed. But i have one real(Public) IP. Incoming request to Proxmox server must be bind Virtualized servers. Dnsmasq installed in Proxmox Virtualization Server. But, incoming request not MASQUERADE in dnsmasq.

But I want to forward all connections all ports coming to example.com to vm? Like SSH, like HTTP/HTTPS, like UDP ports etc?

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to somehow NAT the requests for the different ports - however - technology other than HTTP (including HTTPS), does not work from hostnames - once your local computer has the IP from DNS, it does not pass the hostname again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right use HAProxy :)